# How to detect if user click directly on cell.imageView and not on the label in tableview cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my tableView cell i have:

```
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

How can I detect the user click directly on that image, and not the cell.textLabel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the imageView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    /* ... */
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.imageView.image = /*...*/

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)] autorelease];
        [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
        cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    /* ... */
}

- (void)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[gesture view] superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"Image Tap %@", tappedIndexPath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments have pointed out, you should use an `UIButton` instead. A `UIImageView` is not designed to handle user interaction out of the box and it's much simpler to just create a button, add a target, and add it as a subview of the cell.